# Splitting a row into multiple rows based on quantity and increment a value (SQL Access)

Tags: sql, ms-access

I want to split a row into multiple rows according to a column named "Qta" and incrementing a serial number named "S/N", so:

```
Name    S/N     Qta      
A       004      1
B       005      1
C       007      3
D       004      1
```

Will become:

```
Name    S/N     Qta      
A       004      1
B       005      1
C       007      1
C       008      1
C       009      1
D       004      1
```

I'm using Microsoft Access

I managed to split the rows, but i see no way to increment serial number
Here's my query:

```
SELECT *
FROM Num AS N INNER JOIN MergedQueries1 AS t ON n.numbers<=t.Qta;
```

Obviously i created another table containing numbers

Comment: Advise not to use punctuation/special characters in naming convention.

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
SELECT T.Name, Format(T.SN + N.Num - 1,"000") AS SerNum, 1 AS Q 
FROM MergedQueries1 AS T, (SELECT Num FROM Numbers) AS N 
WHERE N.Num<=T.Qta ORDER BY T.Name, T.SN + N.Num - 1;
```